# Set large buffer/queue on a network interface to emulate bufferbloat

Tags: interface, tc, queue, buffer

I want to emulate large buffer delay on a specific interface. I have a simple dumbbell topology like:

```
PC1   eth0  <-----------------------> eth0   PC2
```

It would be good if I ping PC1 from PC2, the latency about 1ms, but when I start a download the latency grow up to a specific value (which calculated from RTT and BDP). The naive approach (`tc netem` delay) won't work in this case because this not behaves like a buffer delay (more like a propagation delay)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In case if someone interested, its possible with a small custom nfqueue program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tc and a simple fifo queue, you can use `tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent X:Y handle Z: pfifo limit 10000` to set a fifo queue with a 10000 packets length.